# PHP:XML parse: Parsing xml with wildcard

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xpath

i have xml like this

```
<items>                    
 <item>SREE</item>
  .. 
  ..
 <item>ABC</item>
</items>
```

And

```
<items>
<section name='1'>
<item>AA</item>
<item>AA</item>
<item>AA</item>
<item>AA</item>
</section>
<section name='2'>
<item>AA</item>
..
..
</section>
..
..
</items>
```

I have to parse all the item tag in that xml. So I used wildcard in the xml parser like

```
$itemName = $items->xpath("items/*/item");
```

This is only parsing the second xml. I want to write one function which can get the item name from all the above xmls. Please provide me the best way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two possibilities:

1) Use two location paths separated with `|` if the structure is important.

```
items/section/item | items/item
```

2) Use the descendant axis to fetch any item in items at any level

```
items//item
```

this is short for:

```
items/descendant::item
```